# ReactJS: necessity of clearning Interval while using setInterval with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

FTR I am still not clear about meaning of unmounting of react component & its connection with **`useEffect`**.

I've seen and read in different docs and blog-posts where they clear the interval while using **`useEffect`** by returning a function. while coding I've also experienced bugs if I don't clear it. why is it necessary to clear? what does "clean up" process actually mean?

with *timer* example which we can find in many articles they just clear the interval at the end by returning a function for that purpose. I did that too and when I didn't do It, I encountered bugs.

```
useEffect(()=>{
        let interval:any;
        if(isStart){
            console.log(isStart)
            interval = setInterval(()=>{
                setSecodns(sec => sec - 1);
            },1000);
        }

        return ()=> clearInterval(interval);
 },[isStart]);
```

Comment: Your interval fires at some time in the future. Some time between you set your interval to fire, and when it fires, your component could get unmounted. Your component will no longer be displayed, there is no DOM to update. But then your interval callback fires, and it will try to set state on your component instance, which basically no longer exists. Your interval callback code is coupled to your component instance. Without a component instance, it doesn't make sense to have a callback. So when your component unmounts, prevent the next interval callback from firing.

Comment: interesting. I can't clear the interval just by using else, and necessarily have to make it a part of cleanup process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Failing to Clean Up:** If you don't clear the interval, it continues
   to run even after the component unmounts, potentially causing memory
   leaks and interference with other parts of your application.
2. **Incorrect Dependency Array:** If the interval is not cleared when
   isStart changes, it may continue to run when it shouldn't, leading
   to bugs or unexpected behavior.
3. **Unnecessary Re-renders:** Including interval in the dependency array
   would cause the effect to re-run every render, creating a new
   interval each time. This is inefficient and unnecessary.